# Fetch ID from database in C# - Get ID of hovered panel

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

So i'm working on a little bank application in Winforms and is currently making a section where you can create your own savings. I wanted to add a little extra feature, being that you should be able to see how many percentage you are from reaching your saving goal, it works, but it just shows the same number on all different savings, which it's shouldn't. I thought that if I knew the ID, I would be able to fetch that specific saving percentage.

### Code

```
private void panel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        decimal savingMoney;
        decimal money;

        decimal percentage;

        string sql2 = "SELECT * FROM secret.secret where user =  '" + username.Text + "'";
        MySqlDataAdapter ads12 = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql2, conn);
        DataTable td2 = new System.Data.DataTable();
        ads12.Fill(td2);

            for (int i = 0; i < td2.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
            string sql3 = "SELECT * FROM secret.secretwhere user =  '" + username.Text + "'";
            MySqlDataAdapter sda12 = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql3, conn);
            DataTable td = new System.Data.DataTable();
            sda12.Fill(td);

            savingMoney = Convert.ToDecimal(td.Rows[i][4].ToString());
            money = Convert.ToDecimal(td.Rows[i][3].ToString());

            percentage = savingMoney / money * 100;


            bunifuTransition1.ShowSync(bunifuCircleProgressbar1);
            bunifuCircleProgressbar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(percentage);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you just run through the iterations and set the percentage at each iteration, which means only the last iteration will be visible:

```
            bunifuCircleProgressbar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(percentage);
```

Normally, you can read the Name property of the object using:

```
private void panel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Control control = sender as Control;
   
   if (control.Name.Equals("PanelNameYouWant"))
    {
      // enter code here
    }
}
```

here is a quick and very dirty solution, if your DB set has a name for the panel:

`string dataSetName = td.Rows[i][5].ToString();` //expecting the name of the saving is in the 5th column and matches the panel name

and then a simple if condition:

```
 if (control.Name.Equals(dataSetName))
    {
      // enter code here to update percentage for the progress bar
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Moe that's true, I only get the last iteration. Any idea how I can get the Iteration of the panel I'm hovering?

Comment: I was actually thinking, what happens, when your Datasets changes? 
The issue I see here is that there is no actual coupling and once the dataset is gone, the progress bar will take the wrong dataset..

To identify a panel you could probably use the Name attribute or the Tag.

Comment: Hey, I have tried using the name attribute, but it doesn't seem to work. It, just give me the last name from the database :/

Comment: @matteo0402 please check the edit - that should solve the name issue and maybe be of help to get the specific saving for the panel :)